# Can't authenticate Django user in shell

Tags: python, django

For some reason I can't authenticate a newly created user in the Django shell and I really don't know what's wrong. Must be something very stupid...

Start Django shell:

```
(venv) xxx:xxx xxx$ python ../manage.py shell
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0, ...) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (...) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```

Create a new user:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> email = "testemail@gmail.com"
>>> password = "testpassword"
>>> user = get_user_model().objects.create_user("TestUser", email, password)
```

The new user seems to have been added to the database correctly:

```
>>> get_user_model().objects.all()
<QuerySet [<MyUser: testemail@gmail.com>]>
>>> u = get_user_model().objects.first()
>>> u.username
'TestUser'
>>> u.email
'testemail@gmail.com'
>>> u.password
'pbkdf2_sha256$36000$Onrvxuy09b6r$sCuz/2/bIbeg5j7cfO934kCIvzVdxqo1s1v6x6nwYLY='
```

But authentication fails:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = authenticate(email = email, password = password)
>>> user.email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'
>>>
```

I have a custom User model hence the use of `get_user_model()`.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email).lower(),
        )

        user.username = username
        user.is_active = False
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

        ...

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Anonymous")
    is_guest = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The below doesn't work either:

```
>>> user = authenticate(username="TestUser", password=password)
>>> user.email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the user with `is_active=False`. The default `ModelBackend` prevents inactive users from authenticating.

You could enable the `AllowAllUsersModelBackend` backend if you want your inactive user to be allowed to authenticate. Or, if you are just trying to test `authenticate` in the shell, then set `user.is_active = True` first.

```
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user("TestUser", email, password)
user.is_active = True
user.save()
```

See the docs on [authorization for inactive users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#authorization-for-inactive-users) for more info.

Comment: Brilliant spot, thanks! I know this, but completely missed it and was helpless.